# What is the recommended Cache Provider for Spring Cache?

Tags: caching

I am looking for best suggestion on a suitable In-Memory Cache provider to use with Spring Boot Cache. This I need for Pagination implementation on huge data.

Features:

1. WORM (write-once-read-many) caching to follow - i.e. data is stored in the cache once and read many times
2. Data Consistency is preferred choice
3. Each fresh search on same criteria will generate new cache and fetch latest up to date data
4. It could be distributed/replicated cache - need suggestion

So far I narrowed it down to :

1. EhCache
2. Hazelcast
3. Infinispan
4. Redis